# SQL statement for a join in dB2

Tags: sql, join, db2

The following is my sql statement for a join in dB2.

```
select name, address, bloodgroup
from user_tb, health_tb
where user_tb.id = health_tb.id;
```

I am getting the following error:

> "health_tb.id" is not valid in the context where it is used..
>   SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.12.79

I understand that one reason why I could be getting this error is because id may not exist in health_tb, but that is not the case. I hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Thanks for the response. I managed to find the problem. One of the table name was wrongly spelled in the sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should learn to use modern join syntax, although this has nothing to do with your problem:

```
select name, address, bloodgroup
from user_tb join
     health_tb
     on user_tb.id = health_tb.id;
```

A simple search on Google pointed me to the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n206.htm) for this error.  One of the first things it mentions is:

Possible reasons for this error include:

> The specified column is not a column of any of the source or target
>   tables or views of the statement.
>
> - In a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a column of any of the tables or views that are identified in a FROM
>     clause in the statement.
> - A column list of an SQL data change statement specified the name of a column of the target table or view of the statement.

I suspect that the `id` column is really called something like `user_id`.  The working query might look like:

```
select name, address, bloodgroup
from user_tb join
     health_tb
     on user_tb.id = health_tb.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) check if the id column in both tables have the same data type
2) check if there is any trailing space in the column name

```
select '<' || column_name || '>'  from user_tab_columns
where tbname = 'health_tb'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` columns are defined as different types, that could be a problem.